Performance issues with sending lists of messages to Azure Service Bus
I'm working on a scenario where we need to have a capacity of around 1k messages/s published onto a topic in Azure Service Bus. Currently the sending is done in this way:
var messageList = GetMessagesFromDb(); // Gets serialized message content stored in the db

var sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(topicName);

var serviceBusMessages = messageList.Select(x => new ServiceBusMessage
                {
                    MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Body = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventWrapper>(x.MessageContent)),
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    ApplicationProperties =
                    {
                        { "EventId", x.EventId }
                    }
                }).ToList();
await sender.SendMessages(serviceBusMessages);

Using a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch I've timed the sending to anywhere between 50-200 messages per second which seems abnormally slow. Is there a better way to do this to reach higher throughputs? The message sizes are not very large, and typically consists of a JSON with 5-30 fields of data.

How are you measuring overall performance?   Each time you create a new client/sender, the first service operation requires that a new connection/link be opened to the service and auth be performed.  This can easily dominate a test that uses the above snippet.   Likewise, the link/serialization will potentially be impactful.   I'd recommend testing by measuring against a single sender instance that you've warmed up and sending messages that you've instantiated outside the timer.

@JesseSquire I'm using the built in stopwatch to time the different parts of the method. During my tests I found the bottleneck to be the sender as database IO, deserializing etc takes a negligible amount of time while the sending takes 15-5 sec for 1000 messages.
After changing the implementation to use a common sender, I can consistently get around 200 messages/sec after warming up the sender. The problem is still that this is still too slow for our prod requirements of ~1k/sec. This is including the parallelization idea below, however this doesn't really make any difference.

Parallelization would only help if you were to use a different sender, otherwise you'll just queue traffic on the same AMQP link.   If you want to parallelize, I'd suggest using a unique client/sender singleton for each degree of parallelization, which would split your outgoing traffic over different connections.   Depending on your framework/host environment adding .ConfigureAwait(false) may also help.

@JesseSquire By registering a separate singleton for each ServiceBusClient instance and instantiating a sender for each of them, I can get the speed up to around 250-300 messages/sec. I think this will have to do for now, as I can't really find a way to get this to go any faster. Interestingly, more senders (and singletons) don't scale linearly with sending time, and is only /slightly/ better than queueing all the batches on the same sender. There also seems to be little difference between 4 senders and 12 senders, if any, outside of a significantly bigger overhead from warming up 12 senders.

That throughput sounds quite low for a smaller message size in comparison to our performance testing metrics for the SDK.  To understand the bottleneck, we'd need to pull Azure SDK logs and talk more about the app environment, SKU, and configuration of the resource.

One way that I solved this issue for the Standard (non premium) service bus was to enable partitioning, split the messages to send in several chunks and then call SendMessages in parallel for each chunk using a dedicated sender for each chunk. I don't remember the optimal degree of parallelism, but you can do some tests.
var chunks = serviceBusMessages.Chunk(50);
var tasks = new List<Task>();
Int i = 0;
foreach (var chunk in chunks) 
{
    tasks.Add(senders[i++].SendMessages(chunk));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);


I tried this as well, but found that sending in parallell doesn't really make any different. We're also using a Premium service bus.

Maybe you beed to add throughput units.

Use one sender per task.

What kind of performance gains did you get by doing this? It only marginally increases performance in my tests (see my reply to Jesse above), even with 12 senders.

For the premium service bus i remember that when doing this with a high degree if parallelism the cpu metric would go very high and to gain throughput we needed to add TU’s to the service bus.
Our setup was 8 servers with each having 4 sender clients.
